# Run local php scripts from Terminal on remote WAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, network-programming, wamp

I'm trying to connect to a remote WAMP server using a simple php script. I'm able to successfully execute scripts like this one:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    while($counter < 20) {
        $counter++;
        echo $counter;
        echo "\n";
    }

    echo "Done! Counter: ";
    echo $counter;
    echo "\n";
?>
```

But, unable to execute basic scripts on my laptop that try to connect to my remote server, such as below. The following line just freezes and the php script never stops running. I am executing it by `cd`'ing into the directory with the file and running `php test.php`.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database, $db_port) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

This prints `bool(true)`:

```
var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));
```

Do I need to install anything to get this to work? I've done all the usual fixes, changed the `.conf` files on my local server and have an Android app that connects successfully, but now I just want to do operations on a MySQL table from Terminal but am unable to.

Answer (score 0):

The correct call to see any errors generated by a `mysqli_connect()` is `mysqli_connect_error()` and not `mysqli_error($link));`

So change the connection call to

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, 
                       $db_pass, $db_database, 
                       $db_port) 
          or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Or as suggested [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

You will also need to be using a Userid/password that is configured to allow access from a remote connection. The default `root` will not allow remote connections, and should not be amended to allow remote connections.

You may find this [page in the manual useful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html) to create a new user account in MYSQL